# Correct way to query the server for all records, but filter the cached ones in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to use  the filter method in order to prevent unsaved new records (`!isNew`) from being listed/shown before being saved.

So, The official [Ember.js guide](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter%20that%20the%20the%20query%20is), says, the filter method signature is `filter (type, query, filter)` and that the query is an optional argument.

The thing is, When I don't specify the query, I don't get any results, and nothing is shown.

Further digging, And I found out (correct me if I am wrong), That the filter method filters the ***cached*** records, So, This means I have to query the back-end the first time I visit the route?

My question is, Is this the correct way to do it? I feel that there is something wrong with just leaving the query argument blank, Or HAVING to put a blank argument in the first place!

Here is my Route *(which works perfectly and as expected by the way)* :

```
SalesRepsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    # the query left blank in order to get all salesReps from the server.
    @store.filter('sales-rep', {} ,(sr) ->
      !sr.get('isNew')
    )
```

Thanks in advance, And please let me know if I should post any more code/info .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` is meant to be used for querying the store, but in the event that you'd like to trigger a call to the server you can specify a hash as the second parameter.

If you feel hacky (which you shouldn't) about it, you can just call `find` before it and exclude the hash in the filter call.  `find` will asynchronously call your backend and the filter will stay up to date with records as they are added to the store.

```
@store.find('sales-rep')
@store.filter('sales-rep', (sr) ->
  !sr.get('isNew')
)
```